# Help with tricky double integral

Tags: integration, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Consider the region $R$ bounded by the circles
>   $$x^{2}+y^{2}=Ax$$$$x^{2}+y^{2}=Bx$$$$x^{2}+y^{2}=Cy$$$$x^{2}+y^{2}=Dy$$
>   where $B>A$ and $D>C$.
>
> Use the change of variables
>   \begin{cases} u=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\\
>  v=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \end{cases}
>
> to evaluate the integral $$\int\int_R  \frac{dxdy}{(x^2+y^2)^3}\quad
>  (1)$$

**My work so far**: the Jacobian is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\ 
 \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}$$

With $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} $ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$
and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$
: $$J(u,v)=\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}=\frac{-1}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \quad(2)$$

My first approach to get the limits is rearranging $x^{2}+y^{2}=Ax$ and hence $\frac{1}{A}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ hence $1/A$ is a limit and the rest is $1/B$, $1/C$ and $1/D$.

**My questions:**

1. How do I find the limits of integration?
2. How do I express the integral is terms of $u$ and $v$ ?

Any tips will be appreciated thanks!!

Comment: You were given $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ but you need $x(u,v)$ and $y(u,v)$. It turns out $x=\frac{u}{u^2+v^2}$ and $y=\frac{v}{u^2+v^2}$, which gives $|J|=\frac{1}{(u^2+v^2)^2}$, therefore you need to compute 
$$
\iint_{R(u,v)}u^2+v^2\;dudv.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You pretty much got it:
   $$
   R(u,v)=\left\{(u,v)\;|\; \frac{1}{B}\le u\le\frac{1}{A} , \frac{1}{D}\le u\le \frac{1}{C}\right\}
   $$

The Figures below show the case where $A=C=1$, $B=D=2$:

[image]

So the region we are interested in is

[image]

2. We are given \begin{cases} u=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\\
    v=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \end{cases}
   Solving for $x$ and $y$ yields:
   \begin{cases} x=\frac{u}{u^2+v^2}\\
    y=\frac{v}{u^2+v^2} \end{cases}
   The Jacobian of such a transformation equals $\frac{1}{(u^2+v^2)^2}$, and $\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^3}=(u^2+v^2)^3$ therefore the integral equals
   $$
   \int_{1/B}^{1/A}\int_{1/D}^{1/C}(u^2+v^2)^3\frac{dvdu}{(u^2+v^2)^2}=\int_{1/B}^{1/A}\int_{1/D}^{1/C}u^2+v^2\;dvdu 
   $$

This is very easy to integrate, although the final result does not simplify too well. The case with $A=C=1$, $B=D=2$ gives $\frac{7}{24}$.

Comment: Thank you. Btw what program did you use to get the figures.

Comment: WolframAlpha...very handy.

Comment: ok cheers thank you very much